# How do you pronounce the surname Derges

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce the english surname of a famous artist-Derges

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a proper name.

Comment: [This meta thread](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/how-can-the-pronunciation-of-famous-peoples-names-be-too-localized) seemed to reach the conclusion that pronunciation of proper names was on topic if the person named was sufficiently famous.

Comment: Do you mean [Susan Derges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Derges)? Different people may pronounce their names differently.

Comment: Analysis and pronunciation of proper names is on topic; see also [this recent meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/is-the-history-etymology-of-names-appropriate). It's only **giving** names to things that is off topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pronouncing a surname.

Answer (score 1):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTvBSvu0Kdg) of a news report on photographer Susan Derges (the only result for a Google search on "artist derges") has it as **durr-jess**, with the emphasis on the first syllable.

Answer (score 0):

The name seemed to have switched to Burgess in France around 1600. My guess would be something similar to that. There's only 33 people in the US with this name apparently, very little information to go off of besides possibly e-mailing someone with the name or scouring ancestry.com